# Unity ScrollRect many objects perfomance issue

Tags: unity

I have scrollrect setup and over 1000 objects to scroll through. Currently i'm Instantiating all the 1000 objects at once and notice fps drop. I'm using 2d mask and disbale pixel perfect. Both gave a perfomance boost, but i still Think the bottleneck is that i have 1000 objects already created on the scene. Instead create what is visible to the eye.

What can i do? I've looked into pools. But i dont know how i should use it in my case. Since the inventory is dynamic.

[image: Scroll Rect/Inventory setup]

```
public void ShowInventory(PlayerObject player)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.GetContainerSize; i++)
    {
        Item item = inventory.GetContainer[i];
        Button itemButton = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, content);
        itemButton.GetComponent<InventorySlot>().SetInventorySlot(player, item, item.amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a great solution: spawn only enough to fill the portion visible to the user. Where specifically have you run into difficulty implementing this solution with object pooling?

Comment: How do i know which objects are the one visible? Because now i create them all from a list

Comment: That will depend on the layout of your UI, so you might want to show us that — both the appearance to the player and how you've set it up in your hierarchy/inspector.

Comment: I've updated with images on the relevant setup

Comment: You didn't show us your buttons or the type of layout container used in the Content object. That's going to make it difficult for us to estimate how many fit in view at a time. Remember that we know absolutely nothing about your project except what you show us here — absolutely anything Unity can do is a possibility wherever you've left something out.

Comment: Ah i see. Well instead of image. I use Horizontal Layout Group. It fit 6 buttons before i need to scroll size 64x64. Then i use content filter to expand based on how many buttons i have. In this case 1000.

Comment: Sounds like that detail should be in your question. The longer you put off populating your question with a complete demonstration of your situation, the longer it will take to get good answers.